# ASP.NET MVC 5 The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider, razorengine

I met the problem with MvcSiteMapProvider after upgrading from mvc3 to mvc5.
I tested a simple Test view with the following simple web.config, @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() worked fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="XXX.WebMVC" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSiteMapFile" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile" value="true" />

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

But my web.config is much more complex. I updated all the corresponding parts but still met the error with stack trace:

The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage.

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.]
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +401
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +544
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1089
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +119
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +104
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName, ISiteMapNode startingNode, SourceMetadataDictionary sourceMetadata) +232
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper, String templateName, String startingNodeKey, SourceMetadataDictionary sourceMetadata) +70
   MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper.SiteMapPath(MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper helper) +45
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Test_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projects\Drive\drive\Src\Web\Views\Home\Test.cshtml:9
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I put the break point at @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath(), in Watch windows @Html.MvcSiteMap() raised an exception

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap()  'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'MvcSiteMap' and the best extension method overload 'MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.MvcSiteMap(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' has some invalid arguments
```

My Views/Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Could you show me what are the most potential areas causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct upgrade path between MVC versions, you must uninstall the MVC 3 NuGet package and install the MVC 5 NuGet pacakge. There is a separate MvcSiteMapProvider DLL for each version of MVC, so assembly binding redirects won't fix this issue.

1. Backup your solution so you don't lose anything.
2. Run `PM> Uninstall-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC3` in Package Manager Console.
3. Ensure MVC 5.x is still included in your packages.config file. If not, reinstall it `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`.
4. Run `PM> Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5` in Package Manager Console. Answer "no" when asked whether to overwrite any files (these will be files you have customizations in).

The MvcSiteMapProvider.Web package will detect your project is MVC 5 and update your Web.Config file with the correct settings so it will work in MVC 5, so you must ensure MVC 5 is installed into the project before installing MvcSiteMapProvider.

When finished, double check your packages.config file to ensure it has the correct versions installed. Your version and targetFramework might differ from this, but you should definitely have the MVC 5 packages.

```
<package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5" version="4.6.17" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.Core" version="4.6.17" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web" version="4.6.1" targetFramework="net451" />
```

If there are any problems, or if you would prefer to configure it manually rather than using NuGet, you can always add MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5 to a new MVC 5 project and then reconcile the differences in configuration between the new project and your current one.

Comment: In my case - it was this guy in web.config creating problem: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" /> (it was having 5.0 instead of the correct one 5.1) I am using mvc5.